# Ports aren't really getting blocked with iptables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, port

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, I'm under attack from some ports, I blocked all of ports except SSH in my own server, I'm doing that by this way:

```
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

When I attacked my own server and when I looked into packets by TCPDump, there are still incoming packets to 27015 INPUT UDP port! What I have missed? These packets are making my server lag!

Comment: Unless you're very familiar with iptables, it's best to use a firewall building tool such as [ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW).

Comment: You need to look at the output of `iptables -L INPUT -vn`

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm not familiar with ufw, also there are other advanced options to make server secure in iptables which I can't find any reference to do them using ufw.

Comment: You really should stop reading bad internet tutorials, too.

Comment: @AssassiN Can you post the output of the command "iptables -vnL" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tcpdump shows what is going on the wire. It doesn't tell you if that packet will be forwarded elsewhere or processed by the machine or dropped, it doesn't tell you if the machine was generated control messages (ICMP) in response of that packet - it just says: that packet was either entering the machine from the network or leaving the machine.

I believe, in your case the packet to udp 27015 indeed was reached the machine. This is why it showed up in the tcpdump. Then, if the ruleset you posted was really applied to the machine, that packet was dropped by the rule on the line 8. Presence in tcpdump log doesn't say your firewall is not working. tcpdump simply is not right tool to analyse what is going with the packet after it entered the machine.

You can't control what others send. You only control what you do with that. You set firewall to drop everything - which will not stop anybody from sending traffic to you. Think: if they scream your eardrums will oscillate, even if you don't pay any attention to these screams.

This is how "bandwidth" DoS attacks are possible - attacker doesn't need for victim to have any weaknesses, they just flood their full bandwitch with bulk of waste traffic, preventing legitimate traffic to reach victim.

The only way to fight this is to have higher bandwidth (in general, you need more bandwidth than attacker could arrange for attack).

Answer (score 0):

I would take the time and learn iptables and learn to secure your linux server properly. There are lots of bad tutorials out there so watch out, don't just copy and past rules given to you (even mine) unless you know what they do. It's important to learn what each rule does and how it is protecting you and it's also important to add them one at a time and test each time.

Server attacks are just commonplace so you have to learn to deal with it and without crippling your own server, hackers and bots are not going away anytime soon.

I will not post my entire set of iptables rules as they apply to me and might just be pointless for you. The excerpt rules below however might help you deal with ICMP and UDP ports.

That also is a problem with what you posted because you have not explicitly specified any rules concerning udp. See the rules below and customize them as you need, look at the section on dropping UDP ports.

Be very weary of going to extreme measures by trying to drop everything except port 22 to allow yourself in (as you have done), that's not going to help you anything, you have effectively crippled your server and made your own life difficult.

You have to understand where you are being hit and how to deal with it effectively. One mess up with your iptables rules and you can block yourself entirely out of your server and if you do not have root access to it, you're buggered.

You can try these below but please understand these are not de-facto rules for your situation and they are by far incomplete when dealing with all the different kinds of threats out there. My entire iptables setup took me weeks to perfect and I have many other measures in place to safeguard against all sorts of intrusions.

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 17 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 13 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j LOG --log-prefix "[FW - SSH: ]"
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -m limit --limit 2/sec --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-net-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 135,137,138,139,445,1433,1434 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 135,137,138,139,445,1433,1434 -j DROP

-A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```